# "ProductModuleName-Swift.h" not exporting all Swift classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have defined two Swift classes in my Xcode project. Everything else is Objective-C.

To use the classes in Objective-C I'm trying to import `ProductModuleName-Swift.h` but the file contains only the definition for one of the Swift classes. (`SearchViewController`)

This class is being exported:

```
class SearchViewController : UIViewController {
```

but this isn't:

```
public class Socket {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ["Migrating Your Objective-C Code to Swift"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html) in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation:

> - To be accessible and usable in Objective-C, a Swift class must be a descendant of an Objective-C class or it must be marked @objc.
> - When you bring Swift code into Objective-C, remember that Objective-C won’t be able to translate certain features that are
>     specific to Swift. For a list, see ["Using Swift from
>     Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86).

`SearchViewController` is a descendent of an Objective-C class, but `Socket` is not.
To make it usable in Objective-C, declare it as a subclass of `NSObject`:

```
public class Socket : NSObject { ...
```

or declare it as

```
@objc public class Socket { ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I must have overlooked that.

Comment: I've to add that declaring as subclass of NSObject is better. If you don't do that you can't do `[[Socket alloc] init]`

Comment: @wumm: Good point, `alloc` is a method of the `NSObject` class. - (The `@objc` declaration would work with class/factory initializers defined in the Swift class.)

Comment: and what about a swift function and public extension declaration to be used in Obj-C?