# How to call Swift function with more than one parameter from Objective C class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

For example I have this method in swift:

```
@objc class MyClass: NSObject
....
@objc class func viewWithIndex(index: Int, str: String) {
    println(index, str)
}
```

then i wanna call that method in my objective-c class, and i was expecting as simple as this call `[MyClass viewWithIndex:10 str:@"string"];` but it doesn't work.

How do i call it? Please help.

Note: I have already a working swift function call to objective-c `[MyClass showSomething];` so that means i have successfully setup necessary settings to bridge classes. Only the function that has two of more parameters is my problem. :)

Solved:

I dont know what i happened but i just restarted my mac and removed `objc` and it worked with the call `[MyClass viewWithIndex:10 str:@"string"];`. I remember reading in documentation.

[Migrating Your Objective-C Code to Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html)

- To be accessible and usable in Objective-C, a Swift class must be a descendant of an Objective-C class or it must be marked @objc.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you have a compile-time error or a runtime error?

Comment: Is your Swift class a subclass of NSObject? Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605677/productmodulename-swift-h-not-exporting-all-swift-classes.

Comment: I have a working swift function call to objective-c class already but without a parameter or just one parameter. now i want to try two or more parameter. the error it make is `No Known class method for selector viewWithIndex:str`

Comment: Did you do `#import YOUR_PROJECT_NAME-Swift.h` ?

Comment: i already did import that and made the bridge header file.

Comment: i dont know what happened but when i turned on my mac this morning and removed `@objc` it just work properly with the call `[MyClass viewWithIndex:10 str:@"string"];`

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me in Swift 3.0

```
public class func viewWithIndex(_ index: Int, str: String) {
    println(index, str)
}
```

Adding the underscore before the first parameter in the Swift declaration allowed me to call from objective c without naming the first parameter, like this:

```
[MyClass viewWithIndex:10 str:@"string"]
```

Comment: This certainly saved a lot of time. Thanks

Comment: What does the underscore at the start of the method's parameters list actually do? `..viewWithIndex(_ index..`. I can confirm this works for me too, but what's going on here? Does this token have a name in this context?

Comment: @JamesTSnell The _ determines whether or not the parameter name should be used when calling the method.  In the example above, even calling that method from swift would look something like this: `className.viewWithIndex(10, str: "test")`.  If the method definition had the _ before both index and str, then the method call would look like this: `className.viewWithIndex(10,"test")`

Comment: Is it not possible to call a swift function where all parameters are named?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you'll need to mark the function as either public (makes sense) or dynamic. Otherwise it will be a candidate for Swift's optimization (inline or vtable the method) which will make it invisible to Objective-C.

**Try this:**

```
public class func viewWithIndex(index: Int, str: String) {
    println(index, str)
}
```

**Or this:** (doesn't really make sense, but should also work)

```
private dynamic class func viewWithIndex(index: Int, str: String) {
    println(index, str)
}
```

Comment: i dont know what happened but when i turned on my mac this morning and removed `@objc` it just work properly with the call `[MyClass viewWithIndex:10 str:@"string"];`

Comment: OK, it must be the method is already using dynamic dispatch. When its not, I've found the above approach works. . the same rules for the guide on working with KVO in Swift should apply.

Comment: i guess i dont need `public` or `dynamic` or etc coz i have my class subclass to `NSObject`.

Comment: As of Xcode6 beta 6, Swift can still inline/vtable methods/vars on NSObject subclasses. This definitely applies to private vars (which makes sense), but if you have a case where you want it to be private except to the Objective-C runtime, you can add the 'dynamic' modifier.

Answer (score 1):

forward declaration of your class in .h file of objective-c

```
@class <MySwiftClass>
```

import "Productname-swift.h" in obj-c .m class
use

```
[SwiftClass storeWithData:@"Hi" password:@"secret"];
```

SwiftClass.swift

```
@objcMembers class SwiftClass{
   public class func store(data: String,password:String)->Bool{
    let saveSuccessful: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(data, forKey: password)
    return saveSuccessful;
  }
}
```